# how do you install a PEAR package on WAMP, Windows 7?

Tags: php, windows, pear, wamp

I've no idea with command line stuff!

What i've done:

1. changed my php.ini to phar.require_hash -> off
2. ran go-pear.bat

so i'm pretty sure i've got PEAR installed,

now I'd like to install [this package](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff)

I've tried following the instructions but I really don't know how to do things with cmd.exe,

would love some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **PEAR** installed, you just need to issue the package installation command.

Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd>, then type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the CMD window, type `pear install Text_Diff` and you're done.

Comment: do i need to put anything into CMD before that?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by putting somthin' into CMD, just type that command. Afterward you can issue `pear list` to see if that package is already installed or not.

Comment: i get: *'pear' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*

Comment: Did you copy the `pear.bat` into your `System32` directory? If no, Did you add `Wamp's PHP Dir` to windows PATH environment variable to expose that file globally? If no, you can issue `pear` commands from nowhere but `Wamp's PHP Dir`. This means that you have to `cd` to that directory first. If even that fails to work, pear is not installed. Here's a good guide: http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToInstallPearOnWindowsWithWamp